# How to output the value of my radio button when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very noob in javascript. My question is how do I show the value of my radio button when click?

I have this code:

```
   <tr><td width="10px"></td><td width="60%">Neatness</td>
   <td width="40%">
   <input name="neat" type="radio" class="hover-star" value="1" title="Poor"/>
   <input name="neat" type="radio" class="hover-star" value="2" title="Fair"/>
   <input name="neat" type="radio" class="hover-star" value="3" title="Satisfactory"/>
   <input name="neat" type="radio" class="hover-star" value="4" title="Outstanding"/>
   </td></tr>
```

Say when my 1st radio button it will show 1 or so on.. How can I achieve this? Or better yet does anyone know how to do this in jquery.

Comment: Do you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/UpKs5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go ...

```
$('.hover-star').click(function (){$('#someDiv').text($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery class selector and attach to the click event:

```
$('.hover-star').click(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
}
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6srBQ/1/).

Alternatively, you could attach to the change event.

```
$('.hover-star').change(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
}
```

Take a look at the [jQuery selectors documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: hi to all, sorry for my late response. Tried all your codes but it doesn't throw anything. But when I tried the link of Ahsan Rathod in jsFiddle.net its working there. So maybe my error here was I'm still using jquery 1.5.2. Will try to download the latest jquery 1.6.2

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can bind the `click` event to any element with class `hover-star`, and use the `val` method to get the value. This will fire whenever any radio button is clicked (even if the selection does not change):

```
$(".hover-star").click(function() {
   var selectedVal = $(this).val(); 
});
```

You could also use the `change` event, which fires whenever the selected radio button changes:

```
$(".hover-star").change(function() {
   var selectedVal = $(this).val(); 
});
```

You say you want to "show" the value of the radio button, but as you haven't provided more details it's difficult to say where you want to show it! But the principle will be the same as I have shown above - in the event handler function you can do whatever you need to with the value.

**Update** based on comments

As you want to put the value into a `div`, you can simply do this inside the change event handler:

```
$("#yourDivId").text($(this).val());
```

Comment: sorry for the late response. I'm trying to throw the output in my <div class="output"></div>.

Comment: @Dean - I've updated my answer to show you how you can put the value into a `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.hover-star').click(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery COde:

```
$(".hover-star").change(function() {
   var selectedVal = $(this).val();
   alert(selectedVal);
});
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/wVa7c/

Comment: First I tried your code and it doesn't throw any error or alert box. So i thought this must be odd then trace it back I'm using jquery 1.5.2. Maybe this is the problem. I've downloaded the latest jquery and will try it again if it will work. Also I've tried your link in jsfiddle it's working there! ^_^. thanks for the link. bookmark it already